# Laravel input checkbox if selected on edit

Tags: laravel-5

I have an array that I am setting up as checkboxes

```
<?php $buslist = array('Brooklyn','Lakewood'); ?>
 @foreach ($buslist as $buses) 
 {{Form::label('brooklyn_1',$buses)}}
 {{Form::checkbox('BusList2[]', $buses,false, ['id'=> $buses]) }}
 @endforeach
```

Then I switch it to an string with a , using implode
But when I try to edit my information, none of the checkboxes are selected and the information gets lost on update.

What code can i put into the blade checkboxes, if that bus is in my string list?

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes are finicky creatures.  In your form you actually have to do something like this

```
{!! Form::hidden('new-group-user-member', 0) !!}
{!! Form::checkbox('new-group-user-member', true, NULL) !!} Member
```

When a checkbox is not checked nothing gets sent to the server so you never know when to change the value in the backend.  If you add a hidden form field with the same name and a value of 0 it will get sent with the form even though the checkbox is not checked.

Answer (score 0):

In third parameter use `in_array($buses, $buslist)` instead of `false`. Your blade code will look like this:

```
{{Form::checkbox('BusList2[]', $buses,in_array($buses, $buslist), ['id'=> $buses]) }}
```